# Java class has only one constructor, no parameter for constructor, all instances of that class will point to the same object in the heap?

Tags: java, constructor, instance, heap-memory

Have the following case:

```java
 class Bond {
    private static int price = 5;
    public boolean sell() {
     if(price<10) {
       price++;
       return true;
     } else if(price>=10) {
       return false;
     }

     return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] cash) {
     new Bond().sell();
     new Bond().sell();
     new Bond().sell();

     System.out.print(price);

     Bond bond1=new Bond();

     System.out.print(price);
    }
 }
```

It will print: 8 9.
Will all instances that will be made, will point to the same object in the heap?

Comment: why ... do you think that? You think that in order to create a second instance/object, you'll need a second constructor?

Comment: That behaviour has nothing to do with the constructor, but with the fact that you declared the price field as `static`. See: [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

Comment: *"It will print: 8 9"* - No it won't.  Did you test and observe your code before asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a very simple rule in Java: `new SomethingOrOther()` will **always** create a new object (unless it somehow produces an exception).

So the answer is obviously: no, the `main` method you posted will create 4 instances of `Bond`.

Those instances happen to not have any fields that makes them different in any interesting way, but they *are* distinct instances.

The reason it "looks like" only one instance exists is that your `price` field is `static`, which means it belongs to the *class* `Bond` itself and not to an individual instance, which also means there's only one `price` ever, no matter how many instances you have (yes, even if there are no instances at all).

Answer (score 0):

Remove static keyword of "price" to answer it yourself.

static variables hold the same value across all the object instances.